# React Dropdown values conflict

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a nicely working Dropdown that checks whether clicked values are the same, thanks to @David: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-leftpad-sepuly?file=/src/App.js

I use the Dropdown to update parameters with which I render cards in a parent component. This is sent to the parent through clicked function through setVal(id). The issue is, when I need to use more than one state, the functionality of the Dropdown breaks.

```
const ExploreCategoriesDropdown = ({ Title, param, setVal }) => {

    const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
    const [titleName, setTitleName] = useState(Title);

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        APILocalData(param)
            .then((res) => {
                setData(res.data)
            })
    }, [])

    function DropdownComponent() {

        function clicked(name, id) {
            if (name === titleName) {
                console.log("Same Clicked!");
                setTitleName(Title) //When same val is clicked, titleName should default
                setVal() //send empty parameter when value cleared
            } else {
                console.log("Different Clicked!");
                setTitleName(name);
                setVal(id) //send parameter value based on id prop
            }
        }

        return (
        <Dropdown
            isOpen={dropdownOpen}
            toggle={() => setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen)}
        >
        <DropdownToggle className="btn_white_dark_border dropdown_border" button caret>
            <span className="pe-4">{titleName}</span>
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
                {data.map((v, i) => (
                <DropdownItem
                    key={i}
                    value={v.Name}
                        onClick={() => clicked(v.Name, v.Id)
                    }
                >
                {v.Name}
                </DropdownItem>
            ))}
        </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
        );
    }
```

The problem arises when I add setVal(). I am clueless whether I should utilize useState also to handle those interactions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store selected dropdown item in component state, using useState hook:

`const [selectedDropdownItemId, setSelectedDropdownItemId] = useState(null);`

and in the clicked function better compare ids than names.

Also you can store all data in one state, like this:

```
const [selectedDropdownItem, setSelectedDropdownItem] = useState(null);
```

and then in clicked function:

```
setSelectedDropdownItem({ name: name,  id: id });
```